# Como fazer um select com vários `where campo like '%%'` em C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, .net

O `select` abaixo até funciona, mas ele pesquisa todos os campos e gostaria que o `idaluno`, `nomealuno` e `cpf` fossem pesquisados e ordenados pelo `idaluno`

```
SELECT idaluno,nomealuno,responsavel,cpf,rg,fone_contato,desistente 
    FROM aluno 
    WHERE idaluno LIKE '%12%' OR nomealuno LIKE '%%'  OR cpf LIKE '%%' 
    ORDER BY idaluno;
```

Comment: A tag correta não seria [tag:sql]?

Answer (score 2):

O SQL que é utilizado no C# tem algumas particularidades, para você fazer uma consulta usando `LIKE`, você deve estar atento à algumas coisas..

- Se o valor não será `null` ou vazio `""`, `Empty`

Esteja atento também em **NUNCA CONCATENAR**, as strings de consulta. Ou seja a resposta do @Angelo, pode sofrer com ataques de injeção de sql. Whatever isso é conversa para outra pergunta...

A minha resposta para o seu problema..

```
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT passe_os_campos_relevantes_para_voce_aqui FROM aluno WHERE ((idaluno = @id) OR (nomealuno LIKE '%' @nomealuno '%') OR (cpf = @cpf))"), new MySqlConnection("passe_sua_string_de_conexao")){
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomealuno", nome);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", cpf);
}
```

Recomendo nunca comparar com LIKE, valores de chave primária, não há o porque, e nem com o campo de CPF, pois os valores NUNCA serão aproximados ou são eles ou não são!!
Crie uma classe de conexão.
Não sei se você fez, mas como sua pergunta é simples, vale mais umas dicas! ;D

Valeuu!

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma

```
Select idaluno, nomealuno,responsal,cpf,rg,fone_contato,desistente
from aluno
where idaluno = (like '%"+ @idaluno +"%')
OR
(nomealuno = like'%"+ @nomealuno +"%')
OR
(CPF='"+ @cpf_aluno+"');
```

lembre de colocar esse script em uma string que possar ser executada em seguida passando os dados por parâmetro! (AddParameter, se salvo me engano é algo nesse tipo - assim que chegar em casa colo aqui um exemplo da minha aplicação).

Recomendo vc fazer a busca somente por CPF, ou somente por RG. Nesse contexto, o banco poderá retornar vários resultados e não será fácil para o usuário achar o que vc está precisando de fato.

Uma busca por Nome ou CPF já mata grande parte dessa questão.

Espero ter te ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Ao contrário do que diz a resposta mais votada no momento que eu respondo aqui, o SQL que se usa no C# não tem particularidades, ele é o SQL do banco de dados que está conectando e nada tem a ver com o C#.

De fato, é necessário usar a tecnologia do C# para montar o SQL corretamente de forma segura, ao contrário do que fez a outra resposta.

Não faz sentido procurar parte do CPF ou ID. Se puder por alguma razão, talvez só o começo.

Considerando que a informação de busca existe pode fazer o código:

```
using MySqlCommand cmd = new(@"SELECT idaluno, nomealuno, responsavel, cpf, rg, fone_contato, desistente FROM aluno WHERE (idaluno = 12 OR nomealuno LIKE '%' @nomealuno '%' OR cpf = @cpf)"), new MySqlConnection("passe_sua_string_de_conexao"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomealuno", nome);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", cpf);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/SelectLike.cs).

A ideia de nunca concatenar *strings* em consulta também não é bem verdade. Geralmente é, mas é um problema colateral. Na verdade, você nunca deve usar dados que venham de fonte externa, papara concatenar ou fazer outra coisa. Se o dado vier da aplicação, e, portanto, você tem controle total então pode concatenar, se realmente for necessário. Como existe um mecanismo que permite fazer sem a concatenação, em geral é ele que deve usar. Tem situações que a concatenação é a única solução.

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from TABELA1 T1 where CAMPO.T1 in (select T11.CAMPO from TABELA1 T11 
inner join TABELA2 T2 on  T11.CAMPO like '%'||T2.CAMPO||'%')
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor a sua solução?

Comment: Eu precisei apagar registros na Tabela1 que a procura seria pelo campo1, esse campo1 tinha um equivalente na tabela2. Sendo que o campo1 na tabela1 estava com alguns detalhes a mais do que tinha na tabela 2. Sendo assim, fiz um select buscando o campo 1 na tabela 1 com outro alias (T11) e um inner join com a tabela 2 usando o like para vir os registros mesmo com o minimo de diferença. Dai so usar o in () para buscar na Tabela 1 com o alias T1.  No ORACLE  e Firebird || é para concatenar.

Comment: E como a sua resposta serviria ao autor da pergunta (supondo que quatro anos depois ele ainda esteja interessado nisso)? Como você editaria a SQL que está no enunciado da pergunta com base na ideia que você dá na sua resposta?

Comment: delete from email e where e.email
IN (select e.email from emailerrado er
 where e.email like '%'||ER.emailer||'%' )     Assim funcionou melhor!!! com respeito a se serviria a quem perguntou a 4 anos atras, eu não acredito que sirva, mas se alguém procurar pelo assunto, vai sofrer menos que eu para encontrar a resposta.

Comment: Delete!? Não vejo nada na pergunta sugerindo que o autor esteja interessado em deletar algo da sua base de dados.